# Azure AD B2C exception when integrating with ADFS

Tags: azure, adfs, azure-ad-b2c, adfs3.0

I am trying to integrate B2C with my company's corporate ADFS. I am following Microsoft docs for guidance: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-adfs2016-idp

I have followed all the steps mentioned on docs plus the initial configuration, and added the certificate supplied by the ADFS.

When I try to test this by running the sign-in/sign-up policy in Azure AD B2C, I see the link to login to ADFS. Clicking on it, takes me to

I get following response:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/******.onmicrosoft.com?error=server_error&error_description=AADB2C%3a+An+exception+has+occured.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+7b15db4c-e91d-49ce-94ca-7c5525cc10f2%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2017-11-17+09%3a47%3a34Z%0d%0a
```

Is there a way to find out what has gone wrong?

Comment: Also have a log at the ADFS event log.

Comment: @nzpcmad I don't have access to ADFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on logging via App Insights.  See this guide: [Collecting Logs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-troubleshoot-custom)